# Importing a report through the enabler4excel add-in

Tags: vba, excel

This connects to Salesforce to import a report through the enabler4excel add-in. The report overwrites what is currently there on the sheet (2016 Incidents Dashboard). The report contains about 55,000 rows and 10 columns each. I also have 8 columns of formulas (nothing complex) off to the right. The next section autofills the Excel formulas from the last row on the right to match that of the report on the left.

This works, but the only problem is that it seems awfully slow: about 2 minutes. How can I do this so it doesn't take forever?

```
Sub ButtonClick1()

Dim addin As Office.COMAddIn
Dim automationObject As Object
Dim error As String
Dim error1 As String
Dim Result As Boolean
Dim ReportResult As String
Dim LastRowLeft As String
Dim LastRowRight As String
Dim sheetname As String

sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
For Each addin In Application.COMAddIns
If addin.Description = "Enabler4Excel" Then
Set automationObject = addin.Object
End If
Next addin

Result = automationObject.LogIn("myemail.org", "mypassword",              "https://login.salesforce.com", error)
If Result = False Then
MsgBox error
End
End If

ReportResult = automationObject.RunReport("00Od0000004yulX", error1)

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("2016 Incidents Dashboard")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & ReportResult,           Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.Refresh
End With

Result1 = automationObject.LogOut()

Worksheets("2016 Incidents Dashboard").Activate
LastRowLeft = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowRight = ws.Range("M" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("M" & LastRowRight & ":U" & LastRowRight).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M" & LastRowRight & ":U" & LastRowLeft)

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
 Worksheets(sheetname).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: You have already structured your code into nice, separate paragraphs. Which of these paragraphs is taking how much time?

Comment: I suspect a performance review of the code in Enabler4Excel would be enlightening... If it's written in VBA, I'd be tempted to crack it open and fix it.

Comment: I don't see any glaring bottlenecks in that code - if the login part completes reasonably fast, then the problem is probably not even in the VBA code, but in the back-end where the report/query is being executed. It returning a delimited string could mean an awful large string though, so I'd run the query server-side to see how it performs, and then figure out a way to skip the text-handling part and *actually* make that query table *query* the data source. Bottleneck is either the report query itself, or the processing of that huge string; you need to find out.

Comment: The last `RefreshAll` seems superfluous though.

Answer (score 4):

#### Readability & Maintainability

- Use indentation to make control-structures easier to understand and read.
- Some variables are all lower-case, some are camelCase, some are PascalCase. OCD is unhappy :( Use a consistent naming convention. I'd recommend `camelCase`. Either way, choose one and stick to it
- `ButtonClick1` is a rather non-descriptive name
- these "random" spaces before the third argument look strange. I assume they're not there in your own code, right?

#### Compartmentalization

You should be able to make your code into neat little compartments. Those are also known as "methods", "functions", "procedures"  or a handful of other names. All these separate paragraphs that have been mentioned in a comment already can almost be methods. Consider:

```
Set automationObject = FindEnablerAddin()
' [...]
Private Function FindEnablerAddin() As Object
    For Each addin In Application.COMAddIns
        If addin.Description = "Enabler4Excel" Then
            Set FindEnablerAddin = addin.Object
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next addin
    'FindEnablerAddin should be Nothing
End Function
```

This can be applied in other places as well. Note that I have used `Exit Function` to break the loop over all COMAddIns early. This may or may not help with performance noticeably. It usually avoids work, so you should do it.

#### Performance & Nitpicks

- You can usually significantly increase performance by [turning of Events, Calculation and ScreenUpdating in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5925/switch-off-functionality-during-macro-execution#t=201608221632400778598). Don't forget to turn them back on, even if your code falls into an error state.
- Working on the Workbook directly is slow. Then again this looks like you don't have much of a choice here
- Instead of `If Result = False Then` you can use `If Not Result Then`. This is cleaner and avoids the potential for confusion about assignment and boolean comparisons

Comment: The helper function could be generalized to `FindAddin(addinDescription As String) As Object`. There also needs to be a check to see whether the add-in was found, before performing any further actions.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your code:

```
Dim t
t = Timer
```

In your code:

```
Debug.Print "Finished step one at: " & Timer-t
'....
Debug.Print "Finished step two at: " & Timer-t
'etc...
```

Start with that.

Edit: down voters, what is your objection to this? The   OP specifically asked about how to improve performance.  This is the necessary first step in that process.

Comment: While this is may be a necessary first step, you aren't really answering the question: you showed the OP how they could time their code, not specifically what they should to improve the performance. While what you gave is helpful, it isn't actually answering the OP's question.

Comment: RThere is no answer to this question without the OP providing a little more data on where the slowness is.  Since they haven't already done that, it seemed useful to point them in the right direction.  This is not a *competition* or a zero-sum exercise: we're supposed to be trying to help someone out here. I'm happy to delete this once the OP has clarified the scope of the issue (or even if they don't...)

Comment: Thank for all of this.  I went ahead and set timers at each point.  The ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll is absorbing a lot of time.  I have multiple pivot tables that should not take very long to update. The refreshAll does this but perhaps there is another command just for pivot tables and not all formulas.